# How to update the value in one text box based on the value entered in another text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I update the value in one text box (`txtInterest%`) based on the value entered/changed in another text box (`txtAmt`)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use jQuery's [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) method for updating. Using your example:

```
$('#txtAmt').change(function() {
  //get txtAmt value  
  var txtAmtval = $('#txtAmt').val();
  //change txtInterest% value
  $('#txtInterest%').val(txtAmtval);
});
```

Comment: @user459018 It should be using the `val` function, not `text`.

Answer (score 4):

This should work assuming `txtAmt` and `txtInterest%` are `id`s on your page:

```
$(function() {
    $('#txtAmt').change(function() {
       $('#txtInterest%').val(this.value);
    });
});
```

See jQuery's [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler.

Comment: @OBL Don't forget to accept correct answers to your questions by clicking inside the hollow checkmark to the left! Thanks! :)

Comment: `this.value` is safe... no need for jQuery here.

Answer (score 4):

One more method for implementing this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#txtAmt').keyup(function (){
       $('#txtInterest%').val($('#txtAmt').val())
    });
    });
```