# PHP output in the textfield/text

Tags: php, html

i have a little problem about PHP 
there is two input for num1 and num2 
and another input answer,,can the output in the php be putted in the input text answer??

```
<input type="text" name ="num1">
<input type="text" name ="num2">
<input type="text" name ="answer">
```

Comment: You are going to need to give some more details. And post some code if possible too.

Comment: you easily can do with the help of AJAX or jQuery !!

Comment: @ SpitFirez: yes, it can. @riky: why not just settings some php variable at the postback and use that to fill the third textbox? I know your option is nicer, but i can be done simpler.

Comment: how can do that can you give me some sample code in my post..

Comment: @baszz, postback is a .NET-thing, right? Let's not mix the cards, ;-=)

Comment: @ Baszz: how can i do that can you give me some code like in my post??

Comment: @user247245: no....a postback is just the thing your browser is doing when someone submits a form or something...the data gets post back to the server where some server side language is chewing on it. This can be PHP or ASP (.NET).

Comment: @baszz, google postback. The term is ASP.NET-thing.

Comment: @user247245: well...just a POST than...it's the same.

Comment: More people understand what you are saying if you speak Web instead of Microsoft. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//get the values and calc..
$answer = $_GET['num1'] + $_GET['num2']; 
//more secure, $answer = floor($_GET['num1']) + ...
?>
<html><body>
<form method="get" action=".">
<input type="text" name ="num1">
<input type="text" name ="num2">
<input type="text" name ="answer" value="<?php echo $answer;?>">
<input type="submit">
 </form>
...
```

Comment: Brought to you by [Security Holes 'R' Us](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: The link elaborates. You are taking untrusted content and slapping it back in the page. Avoiding that is covered in web programming 101.

Comment: It will help the OP in the sense that installing brakes in a car before providing the car to someone who needs to get from A to B will help them. Getting from A to B is all very well, but doing so in a car that kills you at the end isn't exactly good.

Comment: @Quentin there is no security holes in that code. That's not an XSS cuz attacker can only inject code in a page viewed by himself. That's unless GET variables are stored somewhere and then displayed to other users. But the script in the example is perfectly safe.

Comment: @Ivan — It reads data from the URL. All the attacker has to do is get the victim to click on a link.

Comment: @Quentin, chill out. The OP is entry-level, please adjust your comments accordingly.

Comment: @user247245 — Since the OP is entry level it is *even more important* to explain proper security practises as they are less likely to know to fill in the gaps themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
     if(!empty($_POST['num1'])){
        $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
        $num2 = $_POST['num2']
        $answer = $num1 + $num2;
     }
?>

<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name ="num1" value="<?=@$num1?>">
    <input type="text" name ="num2" value="<?=@$num2?>">
    <input type="text" name ="answer" value="<?=@$answer?>"> 
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="POST ME" />
</form>
```

Not tested btw...

Comment: What are the `@`s doing? I've never seen that placed before anything other than a function call in PHP. If it doesn't escape the output, then this is yet another [security holes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: It prevents PHP from whining about the fact that the variable is not assigned to if there was no postback. It's not a good practice to do it this way but for the example, it works.

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery answer that was suggested by riky has shown up on SO before. Try:

[How to update the value in one text box based on the value entered in another text box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567376/jquery-update-the-value-in-one-text-box-based-on-the-value-entered-in-another-te)

As per the OP's request for an fleshed out version of the jQuery answer, modifying the linked to answer gives something like:

```
$('#num1').change(function() {
  var txtAmtval = $('#num1').val() + $('#num2').val();
  $('#answer').val(txtAmtval);
});

$('#num2').change(function() {
  var txtAmtval = $('#num1').val() + $('#num2').val();
  $('#answer').val(txtAmtval);
});
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Obviously you'd need to include jQuery too.

Please see code in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9KEsY/

Comment: can you make a sample of my post?? or a little code for my post..if your not busy

Comment: The question said PHP, not Javascript.

Comment: It was in response to riky's comment which was marked up, and to the OP's request for a more detailed jquery answer. A down vote seems harsh.