# Set input value from current input textfield on change event

Tags: jquery, html-table, keyup

I have a table with two input boxes.  A and B.  I enter something into input A (and also B) and I want it's value to automatically be set to whatever I type into it on change event.  Is this easy to do?

```
<tr>    
 <td><input type="text" id="A1" name="A" value=""></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="B1" name="B" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: i guess u need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567376/jquery-update-the-value-in-one-text-box-based-on-the-value-entered-in-another-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Description

If you want to keep the two input elements in sync on every keystroke you should use jQuery´s `.keyup()` and `.change()` (for copy and paste) method.

#### Sample

```
$("#A1").change(function() {
    $("#B1").val($("#A1").val());
});

$("#B1").change(function() {
    $("#A1").val($("#B1").val());
});

$("#A1").keyup(function() {
    $("#B1").val($("#A1").val());
});

$("#B1").keyup(function() {
    $("#A1").val($("#B1").val());
});
```

### [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/wkDy7/1/)

#### More Information

- [jQuery Documentation - .keyUp()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)
- [jQuery Documentation - .change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: The problem with keyup is that it won't pick up copy-and-paste text.

Comment: Nice comment! You are right. Do you think a combination of change and keyup answers his question ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
$('#A1').change(function(){
  $('#B1').val($(this).val());
});
```

same for the other input

```
$('#B1').change(function(){
  $('#A1').val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#B1").bind("change keyup", function(){
    $("#B2").val($(this).val());
});

$("#B2").bind("change keyup", function(){
    $("#B1").val($(this).val());
});
```

This way it will pick up each character and will also get copy-and-paste text using the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Change event for input[type=text] do not work as you would expect them to. It basically checks for the changed value of focus out and then fire the event.

I would recommend using keyup event to copy the value accross. it will be as simple as:

```
$('#A1').keyup(function(){
   $('#B1').val($('#A1').val());
});
```