# display attribute conditionally asp.net mvc with html helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

i want to display attribute with condition 
for example if the previous label(number) is 1 so the second(price) should be automatically 4

1-4;

2-5;

3-14,

```
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.number,listItems, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where or how will decide value for Model.number?

Comment: you should use javascript for implementing this kind of problem. On the change event of `number` input, you should change the price input value. You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674878/set-input-value-from-current-input-textfield-on-change-event

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) to handle event dropdown list of `number` changing.

It look like:

```
var $number = $("#number"); 
$number.on("change", function(){
         // do something here
});
```

And then, you assign value for price accordingly.

```
var number = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

var priceAccordingTo = 0;
switch(number){
    case 1: priceAccordingTo = 4; break;
    case 2: priceAccordingTo = 5; break;
    case 3: priceAccordingTo = 14; break;
    }
$("#price").val(priceAccordingTo);
```

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ARkoWW) is the link for demo.

Comment: thank you very much its work, please can you tell me if i had a string by what i should replace    var number = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean. @john smith . My answer is correct, isn't it?

Comment: yes thank you your answer is correct 100/100,but i have another question what if i have a string as a condition

Comment: If your condition is `string` instead of `int` type, You need only to do something like this `var number = $(this).val()`. No need to convert from `string` to `int`

Comment: Have you got that ? @john smith

Comment: You should read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/668611) to know how to accept an answer. @john smith