# Update Textbox Values

Tags: jquery, textbox

From the start I'd like to say I know very little jQuery - I've been using small scripts now for around a week now.  It is a useful tool, but I am unsure if what I am looking to achieve is even possible.

I have a table layout as shown in this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6af/1/), an 8 column layout.  What I am looking to achieve is if the text is MATCH TEXT in column 2, row 2 and the textbox has the number 3 in it that this will then update the other two textboxes with a zero.

I have found this slightly similar code from [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567376/jquery-update-the-value-in-one-text-box-based-on-the-value-entered-in-another-t):

```
$('#txtAmt').change(function() {
    var txtAmtval = $('#txtAmt').val();
    $('#txtInterest%').val(txtAmtval);
});
```

The thing is that while these sets of values appear in my table in groups of three, I might want to autoupdate the the 2nd and 3rd rows, or 1st and 3rd, or 1st and 2nd - so I don't think I can reference the name tag of the textboxes.

I have searched the internet but I cannot find out if this is possilble or how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give all your textboxes the same class name. In your fiddle, I saw that you use the class `errorMessage`. So just do it as simple as

```
$(".errorMessage").change(function(){
//Maybe you have more logic
     if ($(this).val() == 3){
         $(".errorMessage").not(this).val(0);
     }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dx6af/3/)

Comment: This is good, I've modified it slightly to change based on the classes - but can it be expanded to only change if the value entered is 3?  http://jsfiddle.net/hkhUQ/3/

Comment: @Dustin Cook: well, just add one more check if ($(this).val() == 3). Check out my updated answer

Comment: Magic - that got it working - I think I see were I went wrong now.